# Proof of a uniqueness theorem in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, potential, boundary-conditions

I am trying to understand problem 3.4 in Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*:

> Prove that the field is uniquely determined when the charge density is given and the potential $V$ is specified on each boundary surface. Do not assume the boundaries are conductors, or that $V$ is constant over any given surface.

I've tried and this is my approach:

Let there exist two potentials for the given constraints as $V_1$ and $V_2$.And let $V_{3} \equiv V_{1}-V_{2}$.

Both of the potentials$V_1$ and $V_2$  obey :$\nabla^{2} V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$. So $\nabla^{2} V_{3}=\nabla^{2} V_{1}-\nabla^{2} V_{2}=0$.
Also as the potential at every boundary is specified, then at the boundaries $V _3=0$ .
So we have$\nabla^{2} {V_3}=0$ and
$V_{3}=0$ at boundaries.

Since $V_3$ is a harmonic function so we can deduce from above that $V_3=0$ everywhere and hence $V$ is specified uniquely which implies that the field is unique as well because$-\nabla V=\vec{E}$. Which Completes the proof.

The textbook has a different and more difficult proof, and I feel that I'm incorrect. Please hint me how to do this problem or where I'm wrong.  I don't have any teacher to go to. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are assuming   that $\nabla^2\phi=0$, $x\in \Omega$, and   with $\phi=0$ on the boundary $\nabla\Omega$ then $\phi$ must vansish everywhere.     This is kind of begging the question because it assumes  that solutions to Laplace are unique. One can prove  this,  though, by
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla \phi|^2 d^dx = \int_\Omega  (-\phi \nabla^2 \phi ) d^dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} \phi ({\bf n}\cdot \nabla \phi)d|S|\\=0+0
$$
As $|\nabla \phi|^2\ge 0$ the only way that the LHS can be zero is if $\nabla\phi=0$ everywhere, so $\phi$ is constant. Then, as $\phi$ is zero on the boundary, it must be zero everywhere .

Comment: Then you Mike, but could you explain what is $\Omega$ here and being a non English speaker, could you explain what's ' begging the question'. Thank you for your time.

Comment: $\Omega$ is the region in which the field exists, and $\nabla \Omega$ is its boundary. "Begging the question" means to assume what you are asked to prove in order to prove it. You were asked to prove uniqeness, but you assumed uniquness to do do so,

Comment: That is a rather strange notation to denote a boundary maybe $\partial \Omega$ would have been better

Comment: How did he assume it? He used the harmonic property to state the first point in his question. I think harmonic property can be taken as a given

Comment: @Buraian  I meant to write $\partial \Omega$ as the boundary of $\Omega$. Too late to edit now!  What I showed is that $\phi$ being harmonic  plus specified Dirichlet boundary condition gives unique answer for $\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an attempt to convince myself (and sorry I literally don't know how to use latex without the physics package).
Here is a link to the Overleaf [document](https://www.overleaf.com/read/rwxjvtsyjxck)

[image: case1]
[image: case2]