# Can two different electric field exist for the same potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, maxwell-equations

Take the electric field due to a electric dipole. If i do the line integral of this field from infinity to a point 'r' radially then \theta component of field has no role in this integral. So can two electric field exist for same potential?

Comment: [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582456/proof-of-a-uniqueness-theorem-in-electrostatics)?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field due to the positive charge $E_+$ and that due to the negative charge $E_-$ add together to produce the resultant field $E_{\rm resultant}$ as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

The resultant field is at right angles to the equipotential line (central black dashed line and no work is done when a charge moves along that line as the force on the charge is at right angles to its displacement.